# Rotate data in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

i have some data in a matrix that i want to plot as a map.

Unfo, it should be roateted by -90°. Any idea how to do this?

```
set pm3d map interpolate 1,1
splot "cells0.txt" matrix using (1+$1):(1+$2):3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? It is not very clear what you want. Maybe check `help set view` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `1+$1` (value of first column plus one) is `x`, `1+$2` is `y` and `$3` is `z`. Rotating the data set by -90° around the y-axis gives you the transformation `y -> y'`, `x -> -z'` and `z -> x`:

```
splot "cells0.txt" matrix using 3:(1+$2):(-1-$1)
```

Like that you can do any other transformation, `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` are given by the format of your data file. How you interprete them is up to you.